# Windows authentication with active directory groups MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I implement Windows authentication for a web app that is only used internally. This way the users should not need to log into the app, but already be authenticated when they log in to Windows.

I need to give to the users access to different parts of the app according to the group they belong to and according to the group's permissions on Active Directory.

I was able to do it on different Views by using:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"Domain\Group")]
```

How can I do the dame thing on the same View- to give access to different parts of the View according to the user's group permission in Active Directory.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>User Name: @User.Identity.Name</h2>
        <p>
         Test site with Active Directory
            Only users that belong to Group 1 should see this section
        </p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Only users that belong to Group 2 should see this section</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Only users that belong to Group 3 should see this section</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Within the Razor code in the view you can call User.IsInRole() for instance, and put that in an `if` statement to decide whether to show that section of code or not.

Comment: What do you mean "different parts of the view" ? The view runs on the *browser*. If you don't want some parts to end up in the browser make sure aren't sent there in the first place. This can be done in a *lot* of ways. One way is conditional rendering in the view (ie if statements), or  using partial views for parts that need authorization and display only those that have permission. Perhaps put a check right at the top of each partial view?

Comment: If you bind to remote or even local data, *filter* the data before you use it in the view.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What does this HTML code supposed to show? Are you trying to display specific columns to specific users? Display filtered menu elements? This is too broad to answer as-is without writing an entire article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use C#/Razor conditional statements in your view to vary the content according to which group(s) the user belongs to, something like this:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>User Name: @User.Identity.Name</h2>
    <p>
      Test site with Active Directory
      @if (User.IsInRole("Group1")) {
        Only users that belong to Group 1 should see this section
      }
    </p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  @if (User.IsInRole("Group2")) {
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label>Only users that belong to Group 2 should see this section</label>
    </div>
  }

  @if (User.IsInRole("Group3")) {
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label>Only users that belong to Group 3 should see this section</label>
    </div>
  }
```